# Linked list within a linked list (2D linked list?)

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a txt file that contains a matrix of chars(1 or 2 at each position in matrix)

> C P O Hr S A
>
> N Hw N L Z R
>
> W T O O Ta A
>
> I O S S E T

Something like this. What I managed to do is to create a linked list and store every element of this matrix in that list (separately).

```
struct DataNode{
    char data[3];
    struct DataNode *nextData;
};

void initNode(DataNode *head, char x[3]) {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        head->data[i]=x[i];
    head->nextData=NULL;
}

void addNode(DataNode *head, char x[3]) {
    DataNode *newNode = new DataNode;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        newNode->data[i]=x[i];
    newNode->nextData=NULL;

    DataNode *curr = head;
    while(curr) {
        if(curr->nextData==NULL) {
            curr->nextData = newNode;
            return;
        }
        curr = curr->nextData;
    }
}

int main() {
char input[3];
if(in.is_open()) {
        in>>input;
        initNode(head,input);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            dieSide[i]=input[i];

        while(in>>input) {
            addNode(head,input);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

So far, this works as it should, and I guess I'm happy with it.

What I need now, it another linked list, where the elements would still be `char[3]` types, but there has to be first a list containing a row of 6 elements, and then, another list, containing all of those 6 element lists.

I hope I made myself clear about my wishes.

I'm thinking about creating another struct, with `next` pointers to each of two active lists, but still not sure about that idea.

How would you recommend me to go about doing this?

**EDIT**

Just a little help, please...
I have re-implemented all of the functions to suit the struct you (@Daniel) suggested, and they appear to work. However, I need a way to "reset" the `DataNode*` I want to use for creating small lists. This way I only get entire matrix printed as many times as there are lines in the file.
What I have is>

```
char input[3];
int counter=0;
struct DataNode *head = new DataNode; //creates a list of all elements
struct DataNode *head_side = new DataNode; //want to use this one to create smaller lists
struct DieSideNode *head_die = new DieSideNode; //creates a list of smaller lists

if(in.is_open()) {
        in>>input;
        initNode(head,input);
        initNode(head_side, input);
        counter++;

    while(in>>input) {
        addNode(head,input);
        addNode(head_side, input);
        counter++;
        if( counter == 6 ) {
            initSide(head_die, head_side);
            head_side=0;
        }else if(counter%6==0) {
            addSide(head_die, head_side);
            head_side=0;
        }
    }
    in.close();
}
```

This code successfully extracts first six elements, and puts it as a first element of the list, but then it stops working there.

Comment: Any reason you are not using a [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?

Comment: I have a request to use linked lists, not sure why myself... Also, I would like to avoid using any other types like `vector`.

Comment: What exactly is the question that you have? You have stated what you want to do, but that statement itself is basically an answer to the question.

Comment: I have a linked list that holds elements with `char[3]` and a pointer to a next member of that list. Now, I will have n of those lists (all lists will hold 6 elements). How do I create a linked list to hold those 6 element (smaller) lists?

EDIT: Still, I need to be able to access each element of any of smaller linked lists.

Comment: @user3735245 You did nit answer why are you not using std::list?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Seems like a homework assignment to teach linked-lists

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a little hint to get started.  As you know, a linked-list node contains some data and a pointer to the next element of the list.  What you call a "2-d linked list" would actually simply be implemented as a linked-list of linked-lists. Each node in the list points to another linked list. So you will need to define a new type:

```
struct ListNode {
    DataNode* dataRowHead;
    struct ListNode* nextRow;
};
```

What you are trying to do would have 6 `ListNode`s connected as a linked-list. Each `ListNode` contains a pointer to a `DataNode` which is the head of a linked-list for the row that corresponds to the `ListNode` that points to it.

I will leave the implementation up to you.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm starting to get some idea about what to do..

See where I'm creating a linked list of `DataNode`'s? I guess I could implement some counter, create a list same as before, and then, when counter reaches 6, put that list in `ListNode`, then reset counter, and repeat..

Makes sense?

Comment: @user3735245 You could do that if you know that your input will always be a 6x6 matrix. If the input could be a different shape, you might not want to do it that way.  Instead, create a list and when you see a newline, start making the next list.

Comment: Please look at the edit I added to original question. How to re use the same pointer to a list head to create more that one list?

Thanks.

Comment: @user3735245 I don't understand what you are trying to do with the code that you have added.  (By the way, the line that GCC says has no effect does indeed have no effect.  It is just a comparison.)

Comment: What I am trying is to create a list of 6 elements, and then put that list as an element of DieSideNode, reset the list, fill it up with another 6 elements, add another element to DieSideNode etc...

It is supposed to be one `=`, not two...

Comment: @user3735245 I see. That method will not work because your outer linked list will simply repeatedly point to the same linked list.  You cannot reuse the same `head` node.

Comment: So I need to create a new `DataNode*` for every new list I want to include in a big list?

Comment: How would that be possible with the code I currently have?

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, LOL

Isn't there some way I can "move" the pointer, so it "forgets" previous elements, and just start counting new six every time?

Comment: @user3735245 Yes, you can do that. But here's the problem. Say you complete a row and you set the first element in your DieSide linked-list to point to the head of the row. Then you try to use that same head to start a new row. When you unlink all the pointers in the row, those nodes that were originally pointed to are now lost and you're leaking memory. Even worse, each `DieSideNode` will point to the same linked-list, which is the list that represents the last row.

Comment: Yes, I understand how that is correct. Thanks a lot @Daniel you have been very helpful.

I will find another way.